# How to solve a second order but nonlinear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am a physics student and I am trying to solve a central potential problem and came to an equation like this:

$$y^{\prime\prime}+y=\frac{1}{y^3}$$

and I don't know how to solve this equation. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: but I need a analytical solution for that problem....

Comment: so, u r saying that the function does not have an analytical solution?

Comment: I think it was a timing mismatch. The other was moved from physics.SE while the poster followed the advice to repost on math.SE.

Answer (score 2):

The problem simplifies a lot if, instead of looking for $y(x)$, we look for $x(y)$.

Taking into account the classical $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}\qquad \qquad\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}}{\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^3}$$ the original differential equation write $$-\frac{x''}{(x')^3}-\frac{1}{y^3}+y=0$$ Now, let $x'=u$ to get $$-\frac{u'}{u^3}-\frac{1}{y^3}+y=0$$ which is separable. Now , $u=\frac 1 v$ leads to $$v v'=-y+\frac{1}{y^3} \implies v=\pm\frac{\sqrt{2 c_1 y^2-y^4-1}}{y}\implies u=x'=\frac{y}{\sqrt{2 c_1 y^2-y^4-1}} $$ One more step of integration would lead to something like $$x=\pm\frac{1}{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y^2-c_1}{\sqrt{2 c_1 y^2-y^4-1}}\right)+c_2$$